# Efficient string building with immutable strings

Tags: python, string, optimization

In C++ there's vector::reserve() to efficiently allocate memory in advance when building a string. Even without it we can build a string in O(n) amortized.

How do we efficiently build strings in languages where strings are immutable, such as python? The naive method of adding an atom at a time, that works fine in C++ in O(n), seems to be O(n^2), generating O(n^2) garbage for the gc.

Comment: In Python you usually use `str.join()`, which is not going to concatenate a bunch of strings together under the hood (at least in CPython).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of dealing with this in Python is to generate a list of strings (or use a generator), and call `join` to combine them.

```
final_string = ''.join(substring for substring in my_generator())
```